# Building machine code from CLang to C array (LLVM)

Tags: clang, llvm

I have an odd need. I'd like to take a .ll file and generate machine code for the appropriate target from it, in a form that I can embed within another program, without making a shared library. In my primary program, I intend to have it be an array of bytes, that I set execute permissions on, and just call. CDECL.

I can't find the right LLVM tool to accomplish this. Sure, it's easy to generate a .o. But parsing an .o isn't exactly what I want to do right now.

One idea I had was to generate assembler from it, and use some other tool to turn that into some readable format.

Comment: If your code doesn't have external references, then you can convert the object file to binary with `objcopy -O binary foo.o`.  If you need something fancier you can write a linker script.  But, any particular reason not to use a shared object?  This is exactly what they're for.

Comment: The don't have any external dependencies. The function is a simple trampoline to handle packing varargs and va_list before sending it into my actual code (.NET). And I have to support a shit-ton of platforms. Every one .NET supports. Having my build system expect properly setup xcompile environment is become unmanageable, for what consists of like 10 instructions. So many headers.

I think if I can actually commit LLVM IR into source, and then assemble that into the various versions of machine code, then just embed it, it will be much more manageable.

Comment: How do you plan to deal with the platform ABI differences? As for your task... Well, you'd need some kind of linker for this. Probably the closest is to use OrcJIT.

Comment: Different versions for different platforms/ABIs. Same as I do now for shared libraries. I have 15 at this point. Yeah. I was hoping LLVM had some tool that would just let me output into a non .o format. One file per function would be fine, and I'd then just read them in.